# Correct way to filter an array in graphql

Tags: graphql

I have the following arrangement:

```
const Person = function(name, age, interest) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.interest = interest;
}

const people = [
    new Person("rajat", 29, ['prog','food','gym']),
    new Person("ravi", 23, ['travel', 'cook', 'eat']),
    new Person("preeti", 19,  ['comedy', 'arts', 'beauty'])
];

const schema = buildSchema(`
    type Person {
        name: String,
        age: Int,
        interest: [String]
    },
    type Query {
        hello: String,
        giveTen(input: Int!): Int,
        person(name: String!): Person!, 
    }
`);

const root = {
    hello: () => 'Hello World',
    giveTen: (args) => args.input * 10,
    person: (args) => people.filter(item => item.name === args.name),
};
```

When I run the following query:

```
query PersonDetails {
  person(name: "rajat") {
    name
    age
    interest
  }
}
```

I get bunch of `nulls`, when there clearly is matching data in `people` array.

```
{
  "data": {
    "person": {
      "name": null,
      "age": null,
      "interest": null
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you return inside your resolver needs to match the type for that particular field. Inside your schema, you've specified the Root Query field `person` should return a `Person` type, **not** a List (array) of that type.

`Array.prototype.filter()` always returns an array.

If you want to return a single object from `people`, you should use `Array.prototype.find()` instead, which will return the first element that matches the test (or null if none are found).

If you want to return all possible matches, you'll need to change your schema to reflect that (change the return type from `Person` to `[Person]`). Then you can keep using `filter` and it should work as expected.

Comment: I should have read more about `Array.prototype.filter()`. Thanks.